# Div view on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, mobile, device

I'm trying to get adaptive view of my websites. You can see all examples on 
http://fearquest.ru

2 problems:

1. CSS, Display: none doesn't work on mobile phone. I have tried on iPhone and Android.
2. If you open fearquest.ru on PC, it's ok. But on mobile phone you may see that 2 default relatives divs are crossing

How can I fix it?

```
h2#H2_FirstQuest {
font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;   
font-weight: 300;
align: center;
align-self: center;
}

#div1   {

background-image:url(/images/Page-Index/Photo.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;

}

#footer {
height: 100px;  
background-color:#1F1F1F;
vertical-align: middle;

}

#FirstBlock {
width: 100%;
background-color: #1F1F1F;

}

#SecondBlock {
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
#SecondBlock {
visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

Comment: `display: none;` *does* work on mobiles, you must have a media query interfering with the usual CSS

Comment: And while I'm at it, please provide relevant code, and have a read through this -> [mcve]

Comment: I provided the code in fixed question because I cannot put it into comment. Please take a look.

Comment: So where are you using `display: none`?

Comment: Yeas, I deleted it and it works but now strange situation.This works for iPhones but doesn't work for Lenovo S1 Vibe

Comment: Please See last strings in code.